# Loop through <tr> and <td> in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a loop through my array and for every pass- create a table row. However, I'm getting an error `Expected Expression` and I'm not sure why. Does anyone have any ideas? Also, I'm not quite sure why a for loop acts as a function parameter either and an explanation would be amazing. Below is my code.

```
function FormTable(props){
/**
 * props = allStations
 */
return(
    <table className="form__table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Departing Station</th>
                <th>Arriving Station</th>
                <th colSpan={2}>Departure Time</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            { /**
                this self-executing invoked function (IIFE)
                is going to loop through all stations and create
                table data. The reason for this IIFE is because you cannot perform
                stright loops in JSX? Gotta look into it more.

                i = 1 b/c stationIndex[0] = "WarmToDaly" aka property name
            */}
            {( () => {
                props.forEach((stationIndex) => {
                    <tr className="form__table-row">
                        for(let i = 1; i < this.stationIndex.length; i++){
                            for(let j = 0; j < stationIndex[i][j].length; j++){
                            }   
                        }   
                    </tr>

                })
            })()}


        </tbody>
    </table>

)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `forEach` does not return anything (i.e it returns undefined). So better use `map`

```
return(
    <table className="form__table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Departing Station</th>
                <th>Arriving Station</th>
                <th colSpan={2}>Departure Time</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {
            props.map((stationIndex) => {
              return <tr className="form__table-row">
                  stationIndex.map(()=>{
                     //your code.......
                  })   
              </tr>
            })
        }
        </tbody>
    </table>
)}
```

If you want to `forEach`

```
componentDidMount(){

   props.forEach((stationIndex) => {
      var cells = ""
      for(let i = 1; i < this.stationIndex.length; i++){
         for(let j = 0; j < stationIndex[i][j].length; j++){
            cells += "<td>"+{your_data}+"</td>"
         }   
      }
      const row = "<tr className='form__table-row'>" + cells + "</tr>"
      this.setState({items:[...this.state.items, row]},() => cells = "")
   }
}
```

Then inside render call the state,

```
return(
        <table className="form__table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Departing Station</th>
                    <th>Arriving Station</th>
                    <th colSpan={2}>Departure Time</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {this.state.items}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    )}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for replying! I update my code to make it clearer. My function was in a functional component that returned  the table row. I thought about using .map() before using for loops but I can't because when I pass my JSON data from my backend to my frontend, I pass the data through Object.entries() and turns sets the first index of that new array to the first layer of properties in my original object and I dont want that. I commented my thoughts in my code. Please let me know what you think.

Comment: @hello_there in your code you have used `forEach` inside render method. The problem is unlike in `map()`, it don't return anything. If you want to use forEach do it in a separate method. I will update my answer

Comment: oh! I get it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, `props` is an array of multi-dimensional arrays that contain the table-cell data that you want to render.

One approach to rendering this props would be to first replace the `forEach()` with `map()`, allowing each item in `prop` to be mapped to a renderable `<tr>` element (which will contain the `<td>` cells).

To obtain the `<td>` elements for each row, you could iterate the `stationIndex` item in your map function and collect an array of `<td>` elements into a local `cells` array.

The resulting `<tr>` for this `stationIndex` would be rendered with the contents of the cells array as shown:

```
{
    props.map((stationIndex) => {

        const cells = [];

        /* Iterate the multi-dimensional stationIndex array and 
        collect an array of <td> elements */
        for(let i = 1; i < stationIndex.length; i++){
            for(let j = 0; j < stationIndex[i][j].length; j++){
                cells.push(<td>{ stationIndex[i][j] }</td>)
            }   
        }   

        /* Render the cell (td) elements into the tr that is 
        the result of this stationIndex mapping */
        return <tr className="form__table-row">{ cells }</tr>;
    })
}
```